# function to load complete html using html agility pack

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-agility-pack

i have worked on **html agility pack** i know almost every thing to crawl with html agility pack but here is a link.

in the source of the link i can see only 24 products but i want to scrape **links of all the products.**

all the products show only on scrolling. how can i get all those products in my html agility pack source as well? is there any function or method in HAP to do that?

```
https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan
```